# Reset selected value from dropdown using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to clear selected value on a button click using jQuery.

```
$("#cityCode")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
```

This is working fine for a single selector, but if I target multiple selectors like this

```
$("#cityCode, #townCode")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
```

It works only for first ID. Can anyone help me to write fix syntax?

To clear all selected options from dropdown on a button click.

Comment: If it is in a form, you can use `$("#formID")[0].reset()`

Answer (score 1):

As you're selecting multiple elements you need to reset the `selectedIndex` on *all* of them, not the 0th element. To do that you can use an `each()` loop:

```
$("#cityCode, #townCode").each((i, el) => el.selectedIndex = 0);
```

Alternatively, if the first option in both dropdowns has an empty value, eg. `<option value="">Please select</option>`, then you can use the `val()` method which will implicitly loop for you:

```
$("#cityCode, #townCode").val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [.prop() method](https://api.jquery.com/prop/):

### Set the selected option to `0` index

This is considered **bad practice** since the `defaultSelected` might not necessarily be the option at index `0`. Such depends on which option had originally the `selected` HTML attribute set (see the other example). This is only OK *-ish* if you don't use such attribute on your Option elements.

```js
$("#cityCode, #townCode").prop("selectedIndex", 0);
```

```html
<select id="cityCode">
  <option>111</option>
  <option selected>222</option>
  <option>333</option>
</select>

<select id="townCode">
  <option>aaa</option>
  <option selected>bbb</option>
  <option>ccc</option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In vanilla JavaScript:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#cityCode, #townCode").forEach(elSelect => {
  elSelect.selectedIndex = 0;
});
```

### Reset option to original defaultSelected index

Notice that the above sets *specifically* the index to `0` (first option element), which might not be the original `defaultSelected`.

To account for this use:

```js
$("#cityCode").val("333"); // just to force emulate some dynamic change
$("#townCode").val("ccc");

$("#cityCode, #townCode").prop("selectedIndex", function() {
  const idx = [...this.options].findIndex((opt) => opt.defaultSelected);
  return idx < 0 ? 0 : idx;
});
```

```html
<select id="cityCode">
  <option>111</option>
  <option selected>222</option>
  <option>333</option>
</select>

<select id="townCode">
  <option>aaa</option>
  <option selected>bbb</option>
  <option>ccc</option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Reset form

If instead, you wish to reset the entire form use:

```js
$("#someForm")[0].reset();
```

### Don't use `.val("")`

as suggested in other answers... don't use `.val("")`. Here's why:

```js
$("#cityCode, #townCode").val("");
```

```html
<select id="cityCode">
  <option>111</option>
  <option selected>222</option>
  <option>333</option>
</select>

<select id="townCode">
  <option>aaa</option>
  <option selected>bbb</option>
  <option>ccc</option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
  $("#cityCode, #townCode").each(function(){
                    $(this).selectedIndex = 0;
                });
```

Comment: `this.selectedIndex = 0;`